# Поставить тире, запятую или оставить без знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Гнилая капуста и та красивее тебя.

---

Нужно ли ставить тире или запятую перед "и"? 
Хочу отправить пост в группу, но не хочу опозориться своей безграмотностью :(

Comment: Думаю, если вы не боитесь опозориться содержанием, то форма как-нибудь переживет.

Comment: Нет, это цитата из мультсериала, я нарезку из кадров делаю.

Comment: А, тысячу извинений. Тогда - тире. Запятая, согласен, тут неуместна, а без тире чисто визуально - плохо смотрится. Полный ответ набросаю чуть позже, если нужно. .

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ставится запятая перед частицей **и,** за которой следует указательное местоимение **тот (та, то, те),** употребленное для усиления значения предшествующего члена предложения: Даже стол и тот как-то сдвинулся с места (Панф.).

См.: Академический справочник.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.